# How to change the protection level on a variable in VB.net Window Forms

Tags: vb.net, forms, winforms

I am having trouble getting some code to find a variable that I declare when the form opens.
Here is my code:

```
Public Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim test As Double
    test = 1
End Sub
Public Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
If test = 1 Then
        PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.cbreak1
        test = 2
End If
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: test is declared within the method so it can't be referenced out of it. Its a context variable. At the end of the sub, test is destroyed.

Comment: This is what's known as _Scope_ (in your case _Method Scope_ or _Procedure Scope_), which is very fundamental programming. I highly recommend you read up on how it works: [Scope in Visual Basic | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/declared-elements/scope)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable "test" is declared inside the method, it does not exist outside of it. If you need to, you have to declare it as part of the class.

```
Dim test As Double

Public Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    test = 1
End Sub

Public Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If test = 1 Then
        PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.cbreak1
        test = 2
    End If
End Sub
```

As tempting as it might be, try not to declare all your variable in the class. In your case, it could just be a static variable.